# How do I use sql where and from clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this is the question.

The manager in the human resources department needs a listing of department managers, their salaries.  The query must display the Department Name, First Name and Last Name (concatenate the name columns into a single column), and Salary column values.  Name the columns in the result table as follows:  Department, Manager, and Salary. Sort the result table by Salary.  Use the WHERE clause to join the tables.  Use COLUMN-FORMAT commands to product a listing that fits easily on one page.

And this is what I have for it so far

```
SELECT FirstName||' '||LastName "Manager" FROM  Employee
SELECT LastName "Last Name", FirstName "First Name", 
DepartmentName "Department Name", Salary "Salary" 
FROM Employee, Department
WHERE Employee.DepartmentNumber = Department.DepartmentNumber
```

I know that it is wrong but I cant figure out how to do it differently

I am also struggling with another question as well it is

Rewrite the query for the above question by using the FROM clause to join the tables.

So far I have this, but in not sure how to do the concatenate part.

```
SELECT LastName "Last Name", FirstName "First Name",
DepartmentName "Department Name", Salary "Salary"
FROM Employee e JOIN Department d 
ON (e.DepartmentNumber = d.DepartmentNumber);
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: SQL Server  does not comply with the SQL standard regarding string concatenation. You have to use `+` instead of `||` there

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate strings in `SQL SERVER` you need to use `+` operator

```
SELECT FirstName+' '+LastName as  [First Name],
DepartmentName [Department Name], Salary 
FROM Employee e JOIN Department d 
ON (e.DepartmentNumber = d.DepartmentNumber)
Order by Salary
```

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` then use `CONCAT` function

```
CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) as  [First Name]
```

**Note :** Using `Where` clause to join two tables is old style and not recommended always use Explicit `INNER JOIN` syntax